# Play framework, fake formdata for batch call

Tags: playframework-2.2

I'm trying to implement a batch call method for inserting a lot of objects at once.

The thing is, the method for individual inserts gets a Form for the insert, which is bound from the Request.

My idea here is to retrieve a json array, with all the data for the required inserts.

I would then loop over it and call the regular insert method for each one. But that means having to pass the data to the Form. But the Form gets data from seeing if there's data attached to the HTTP Request. But there isn't an HTTP Request.

Is there a way for me to do this without using a FakeRequest?

Comment: why not to create entity object direct by json data and save it? infact thats the same you do in case of form

Comment: @singhakash I did it like that, but I got interested in how to send the Form like this. I just want to know if there's an option to do this.